# Why when trying to draw a triangle I'm getting exception out of bounds on the uv's?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It's drawing a triangle but also give exception.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MeshGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject meshPrefab;
    public Vector3[] newVertices;
    public Vector2[] newUV;
    public int[] newTriangles;

    private Mesh mesh;

    void Start()
    {
        Mesh meshprefab = meshPrefab.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
        newVertices = meshprefab.vertices;
        newUV = meshprefab.uv;
        newTriangles = meshprefab.triangles;


        mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        mesh.Clear();
        mesh.uv = new Vector2[] { new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(0, 0.25f), new Vector2(0.25f, 0.25f) };
        mesh.vertices = new Vector3[] { new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0.25f, 0), new Vector3(0.25f, 0.25f, 0) };
        mesh.triangles = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
    }
}
```

The exception is on the line:

```
mesh.uv = new Vector2[] { new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(0, 0.25f), new Vector2(0.25f, 0.25f) };
```

Mesh.uv is out of bounds. The supplied array needs to be the same size as the Mesh.vertices array.
UnityEngine.Mesh:set_uv(Vector2[])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the vertex array assignment statement to before the uv one, because Unity currently thinks that the number of vertices is zero.

```
mesh.vertices = ...
mesh.uv = ...
```